# How to transform strings based on these conditions? (no-spam email to real e-mail)

Tags: powershell

I have a list of email, for example

```
johnsmith at gmail dot com
username at gmail.com
random atsign outlook dot com
```

The username and the provider is always separated by a custom word between spaces.
The problem here is that the domain can have a custom separator like this (dot, or any text) OR just a dot, like gmail.com
If it would have only spaces, I would simply read the lines and split them at the spaces, then write the first, @, the third, . and then the fifth items from the list.
However, the possible john at gmail.com format is problematic for me. How could I handle this format along with the simple name at gmail dot com formats in one script?

Comment: [1] what have you tried so far & how did it fail to do what you need? [2] please provide at least one sample data point for your various possible inputs. [3] please provide the desired output for each sample input & the logic to get from input to output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the examples you give, a bit of regex will do it:

```
$emails = @"
johnsmith at gmail dot com
username at gmail.com
random atsign outlook dot com
"@ -split '\r?\n'

$emails | ForEach-Object {
    # replace all repeating whitespace characters by a single space
    # and split 3 parts 
    $pieces = $_ -replace '\s+', ' ' -split ' ', 3
    # output the username, followed by the '@' sign, followed by the domain
    '{0}@{1}' -f $pieces[0], ($pieces[2] -replace ' [^\.]+ ', '.')
}
```

Output:

> ```
> johnsmith@gmail.com
> username@gmail.com
> random@outlook.com
> ```

Regex details for the domain part:

```
\         Match the character “ ” literally
[^\.]     Match any character that is NOT a “A . character”
   +      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\         Match the character “ ” literally
```

Answer (score 0):

A **PowerShell v6.1+ solution**, which uses the ability of the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to accept a *script block* (`{ ... }`) to process each match.

<sup>For a solution that also works in Windows PowerShell, see [Theo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236986/45375).</sup>

```
# Simulate an array of input lines.
$emails = @'
johnsmith at gmail dot com
username at gmail.com
random atsign outlook dot com
'@ -split '\r?\n'

# Synthesize a valid email address from each line.
# (If the lines came from file, say, 'emails.txt', replace `$emails`
#  with `(Get-Content emails.txt)`)
$emails -replace '^([^ ]+) \w+ ([^ ]+|[^ ]+ [^ ]+ [^ ]+)$',
  { '{0}@{1}' -f $_.Groups[1].Value, ($_.Groups[2].Value -replace ' [^ ]+ ', '.') }
```

Note:

- I've assumed that the tokens in your input line are separated by *exactly one space* char.; to support multiple spaces as well, replace   in the regex with `\s+`.
- `[^ ]+` is a nonempty (`+`) run of non-space (`[^ ]`) characters; loosely speaking, a word.
- The regex matches each line in full, capturing the parts of interest via capture groups (`(...)`)
- The script block (`{ ... }`) receives the match at hand in automatic variable `$_`, as a [`Match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.match) instance, from which the capture groups can be extracted via `.Groups[<n>].Value`), starting with index `1`.

The above yields:

```
johnsmith@gmail.com
username@gmail.com
random@outlook.com
```